# Android NDK STL c++_shared w/LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD results in std::stringstream NOP

Tags: android, c++, stl, android-ndk

**tl;dr:** The question is for an explanation for why `std::stringstream` "fails", and why it fails in the way it does (by simply doing nothing), when linking to a rebuilt c++_shared library.

A minimal example:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Hello World";
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,
                   "APP",
                   "Length: %i", ss.str().size());
```

When compiling the project with

```
APP_STL := c++_shared
LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := true
```

The output is `Length: 0`. When using `APP_STL := c++_static` or `LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := false`, the `stringstream` works as expected, with `Length: 11` as output.

I'm using many parts of the STL, and the only noticeable difference I've seen so far is this silent `NOP` `stringstream`. I've also tested this by modifying the `libgl2jni` NDK sample, adding the Application.mk file as:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_STL := c++_shared
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a #armeabi-v7a x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := true
```

I've tested the various permutations of `APP_OPTIM` as release/debug, `APP_STL` as c++_shared/c++_static, and `LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD` as true/false, on a Nexus-4, with both `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` as target `ABI`. This is the result:

```
|-------------+-----------+----------------------+---------+------------------|
| ABI         | stl c++_? | LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD | optim   | Result           |
|-------------+-----------+----------------------+---------+------------------|
| armeabi     | static    | true                 | release | OK               |
|             | static    | true                 | debug   | OK               |
|             | static    | false                | release | BUILD FAILED [1] |
|             | static    | false                | debug   | BUILD FAILED [1] |
|             | shared    | true                 | release | NOP              |
|             | shared    | true                 | debug   | NOP              |
|             | shared    | false                | release | OK               |
|             | shared    | false                | debug   | OK               |
|-------------+-----------+----------------------+---------+------------------|
| armeabi-v7a | static    | true                 | release | OK               |
|             | static    | true                 | debug   | OK               |
|             | static    | false                | release | OK               |
|             | static    | false                | debug   | OK               |
|             | shared    | true                 | release | NOP              |
|             | shared    | true                 | debug   | NOP              |
|             | shared    | false                | release | OK               |
|             | shared    | false                | debug   | OK               |
|-------------+-----------+----------------------+---------+------------------|
```

[1] /opt/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi/libc++*static.a(ios.o):/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/tmp/build-21097/build-libc++/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/src/ios.cpp:function std::*_1::ios_base::xalloc(): error: undefined reference to '__atomic_fetch_add_4'

*PS:* Make sure to do a `ndk-build clean` in between these tests.

**The question:**
Could anyone give some insight into why `std::stringstream` fails given these circumstances, and why it fails by just doing a NOP on any data that is streamed to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

I can't answer why the NOP is occurring in some permutations. But I did manage to find out about the build failures.

I was in a worse situation than you. I was experiencing the build failures relating to the combination of using c++_static and the default value for LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD (false) and had no idea why.

Thanks to you for sharing your research into the various permutations of linking STL - I was able to jump straight to the salient documentation to fix the build error.

> It's likely that you need libatomic if you #include . Add "LOCAL_LDLIBS += -latomic" for ndk-build

To be able to use libatomic you need to set your NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION to 4.8

Comment: I was having a similar issue and adding that lib did the trick for me :)

Comment: loading libatomic helped for building for armeabi target

Comment: Strange, but after some struggling I was only able to compile after adding
'APP_LDFLAGS += -latomic '
LDLIBS didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
```

It seems that the code snippet doesn't really called atomic_fetch_add(). With --gc-sections LD option, the linker will eliminate the unused code and data from the final executable or shared library. So that the dependency of atomic_fetch_add() is likely to be removed.

Description of "--gc-sections":
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Compilation-options.html

Some other infomation:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68779

Comment: Can you explain what these flags do? Your answer need to be instructional, not just something to type and solve the problem.