# NDK not identifying certain header files like <mutex> and <future>

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to integrate C++ files into my android project.
I tried using Android Studio's ndk feature but I got several issues. So I prevented Android Studio from creating its own Android.mk file by making the following changes in my .gradle file -

```
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] 
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
   }
```

And I created a gradle task to compile my library files.

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine ndk_build_path, '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

where "ndk_build_path" is defined in gradle.properties file

```
ndk_build_path=/Users/shadabunique/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build
```

The platform I'm using is Mac.

The header files in my C++ files are  -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

#include <ctime>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
```

I also created Application.mk file with contents -

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_STL :=stlport_static
```

I have put all the C++ files, Android.mk and Application.mk files in src/main/java/jni folder.

I am getting the following errors -

```
mutex: No such file or directory
future: No such file or directory
```

Please help !

Comment: Q: Have you tried `#include "mutex.h"` and `#include "future.h"`?

Comment: I tried and the error message I got is -  mutex.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by making the  following changes-

Android.mk -

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := myLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libmyLib.so
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL :=c++_static
```

Hope someone could get some help with this.

Comment: Multiple `APP_STL:=` statements have no effect. Only the last one holds.

Comment: yeah , plz edit this answer , someone will get it wrong , only the last "APP_SLT:=" have effect , the others are ignored this is an assigment operator not a "+=" , that you can't use in this case .

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem when porting my c++11 code over ndk.

NDK (10e) keeps complain missing things for `gnustl_xxx` or `stlport_xxx`, but I found it smooth with `c++_static`.

So, you may try add this to Application.mk

```
APP_STL:=c++_static
```

and in Android.mk

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  += -std=c++11
```

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting this error - Error:error: undefined reference to '__atomic_fetch_add_4'

Comment: Are you using llvm or gcc? I'm using `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9`

Comment: quick search you got solution for atomic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041401/android-ndk-stl-c-shared-w-libcxx-force-rebuild-results-in-stdstringstream-n

Comment: I went through the discussion provided in the thread shared by you. But it's still not working and throwing the same error.

Comment: I added LOCAL_LDLIBS += -latomic in Android.mk file and the project is getting compiled now. Thanks :)